# How to get MIDI output from a Windows application via Wine

Tags: 12.04, wine, indicator-sound, midi

I develop a windows application and am curious whether it works via Wine. The application runs fine with Wine but I get no sound. In fact, I'm not sure whether my ubuntu installation has MIDI capabilities. The sound output settings shows "LFE on Separate Mono Output" one with "no amplifier" and another with "amplifier". They both function. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 as a client on virtualbox that runs on windows 7.

Thanks for any suggestion!

EDIT: virtual box hosted by windows 7, ubuntu running as a client in virtualbox.

Comment: which way around do you mean it?  a really clear way to refer to stuff when doing desktop virtualization is host/guest.  client is not so clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple suggestion: Try installing Timidity, which should provide your Ubuntu with a MIDI synthesizer, enabling it to play MIDI output.

Comment: Excellent idea! I had already done that, but then my program complained of having no MIDI output ports. Two days of being logged off were enough to remove that error. All works fine now. Thanks.